# Neural Network is not predicting the results

Tags: regression, neural-networks

I am testing the backpropagation algorithm for a multilayer perceptron. My net architecture have 3 neurons with sigmoid as activation function. My data is came from a linear regression problem, but I'm just trying to implement the regression with neural networks.
The problem is, my net is not predicting the values. As far as I know, a neural network can approximate a huge number of functions beacuse of its non-linearity, but in this case, is a linear problem. Should it be easier to it to predict the results? Below I write the code: I'm using Python 3 with Anaconda 3.6 environment.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import random

random.seed(1)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1./(1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_(x):
    return sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x))

income = np.array([685, 683, 526, 662, 536, 627, 520, 423,
          343, 513, 462, 383, 460, 517, 454, 448,
          1076, 970, 722, 681, 814, 800, 782, 775,
          689, 731, 1499])

income_ = income/np.max(income)

scholarship = np.array([5.7, 6, 4.5, 4.9, 4.7, 5.5, 4.5, 3.9,
               3.6, 4.5, 4.3, 3.5, 4.1, 4.6, 3.7, 4,
               6.8, 7.1, 5.7, 5.4, 6.3, 6.4, 6, 5.4,
               5.5, 5.7, 8.2])

scholarship_ = scholarship/np.max(scholarship)

w1 = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5, size = (3, 1))
w2 = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5, size = (1, 3))
b1 = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5, size = (3, 1))
b2 = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5, size = (1, 1))

eta = 0.05
emax = 1e-7

epoch = 30
E = 0

for i in range(epoch):  
    E_ = E

    for j in range(len(income)):
        i1 = np.dot(w1, np.array([[scholarship_[j]]])) + b1
        y1 = sigmoid(i1)
        i2 = np.dot(w2, y1) + b2

        dW2 = np.dot((income_[j] - i2), sigmoid_(i2))
        w2 += eta*dW2*y1.T
        b2 += eta*dW2

        dW1 = np.dot(dW2, w2).T * sigmoid_(i1)
        w1 += eta*dW1*np.array([scholarship_[j]])
        b1 += eta*dW1

    E = []

    for k in range(len(income)):
        i1 = np.dot(w1, np.array([[scholarship_[k]]])) + b1
        y1 = sigmoid(i1)
        i2 = np.dot(w2, y1) + b2
        E.append((income_[k] - i2[0][0])**2)

    E = sum(E)/(2*len(E))

    if abs(E_ - E) <= emax:
        break

    print('Error: ', E, ' at epoch: ', i)

nn = []

for l in range(len(income)):
        i1 = np.dot(w1, np.array([[scholarship_[l]]])) + b1
        y1 = sigmoid(i1)
        i2 = np.dot(w2, y1) + b2
        nn.append(i2[0][0])

plt.plot(scholarship_, income_, 'ro', scholarship_, nn, 'bo')
plt.show()
plt.plot(income_, nn, 'yo')
plt.show()
```

And the resulting graphs are:

[image: The Neural Network x X_data]

The red points are the *x data* with *y data*, the blue one are the *x data* with the *net predicts*

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong (I don't know python), but it kind of looks like you've written your own neural network code rather than use a plugin. Furthermore there doesn't appear to be any code for the actual training of the data (the gradient descent of the coefficients to minimise the error w.r.t the data). It looks like your NN isn't capable of actually learning, it's just sending data through static neurons.

Comment: I am trying to implement a neural network using the algorithm and examples from the Simon Haykin book: *Neural Networks and Learning Machines*. The neurons are, in every ith repetition, actualizing their values computing the dW, which is the derivative of the cost function with respect to the weights. The problem, I suppose is about the gradients, if are they correctly calculated.